# How do I go about drawing an hourglass using characters with C++?

Tags: c++, loops, oop, character

So, the goal in the end is create code that draws an hourglass depending on the size of the size of the triangle. For instance, if I have an object that is initialized as Hourglass h1(6,'^','-') then the object has a size of 6 and the border character is '^'. While the filler character is '-'. In the end, the result would look like this:

[Triangle that has a size of 6 (2 triangles creates hourglass)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXsey.png)

So far, this is all I've got for my draw function:

```
//Purpose is to draw the hourglass 
void Hourglass::Draw()
{
    char space=32;          //Stores spaces

    if (size==1)            //If the size is 1, then display the border
        cout << border << "\n";

    else {                  //just draw size-1 border characters
        for (int i=0; i<size-1;i++)  
            cout << border << space;
    }

    cout <<"\n";
}
```

This is where I am stuck. I'm not really sure as to how can I go about drawing the hourglass as the size increases past 1. I do think that I need to write a for loop within a for loop but once again, I'm not sure at all how to go about it.

If anyone is able to, please steer me in the right direction. I'm not looking for the answer to be given to me. I would rather be told as to how can I get to the right answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Think about how wide the hourglass needs to be on each line, and how indented it must be when that line starts.  And also how many lines you will require.

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate and closed, although it should be noted that the older question asks for a simpler hourglass version, with one character acting as border and filler.

Answer (score 1):

I have organised the solution below into a few subroutines. The algorithm slices the hourglass in layers, each represented by a printed `string`. Each subroutine outputs a region in the hourglass.

It is important to note that each line drawing the hourglass has whitespace interspersed between `b` (border) and `f` (filler) symbols. Hence the need to define a `dim = size + (size - 1)` as length of each line, with starting and trailing whitespace as opportune.

The algorithm:

1. `main()` calls `hourglass()`, which sets up a string of length `dim = size + (size - 1)` filled with whitespaces;
2. `hourglass()` then calls a series of functions, each tasked with drawing one of the regions our hourglass figure is sliced into;
3. each function adds `^` or `*` symbols as necessary to the `string` - or group of `string`s - of whitespaces acting as a base.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void baseline(int dim, char b) {
    string str(dim, ' ');

    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j += 2)
        str[j] = b;
    cout << str << endl;
}

void triangleDown(string str, int size, int dim, char b, char f) {
    for (int i = 1; i != size-1; i++) {
        str = string(dim, ' ');
        str[i] = b;
        for (int j = i+2; j <= dim - 2*i; j+= 2) {
            str[j] = f;
        }
        str[dim-i-1] = b;
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}

void centreline(string str, int dim, char b) {
    str[dim/2] = b;
    cout << str << endl;
}

void triangleUp(string str, int size, int dim, char b, char f) {
    for (int i = size-2; i != 0; i--) {
        str = string(dim, ' ');
        str[i] = b;
        for (int j = i+2; j <= dim - 2*i; j+= 2) {
            str[j] = f;
        }
        str[dim-i-1] = b;
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}

void hourglass(int size, char b, char f) {
    int dim = size + (size - 1); // size of edge of the (square) frame
    string str(dim, ' ');

    baseline(dim, b);
    triangleDown(str, size, dim, b, f);
    centreline(str, dim, b);
    triangleUp(str, size, dim, b, f);
    baseline(dim, b);
}

int main() {
    hourglass(6, '^', '*');

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output compiled with https://godbolt.org/z/9GqPoh:

```
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ * * * ^ 
  ^ * * ^  
   ^ * ^   
    ^ ^    
     ^     
    ^ ^    
   ^ * ^   
  ^ * * ^  
 ^ * * * ^ 
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Giorge is a good start. But it's easy to simplify it:

Here's my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void hourglass(size_t width, char outer, char inner)
{
    if (width < 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    size_t rows = width * 2 - 1;

    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        size_t r = row;
        if (row > rows / 2)
        {
            // if we're drawing a row on the bottom half
            // normalize it to be the mirror of a row on the top half
            r = rows - row - 1;
        }

        // draw r leading spaces
        for (size_t i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }

        // draw width-r charaters (including spaces in between)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < width-r; i++)
        {
            size_t last = width - r - 1;
            char c = inner;

            // if it's the top row, bottom row, or first char, or last char of the row
            // then draw an outer character
            if ((i == 0) || (i == last) || (r == 0))
            {
                c = outer;
            }

            cout << c;

            if (i != last)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    hourglass(5, '^', '*');
    cout << endl << endl;
    hourglass(6, '^', '*');
}
```

When run:

```
^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ * * ^
  ^ * ^
   ^ ^
    ^
   ^ ^
  ^ * ^
 ^ * * ^
^ ^ ^ ^ ^


^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ * * * ^
  ^ * * ^
   ^ * ^
    ^ ^
     ^
    ^ ^
   ^ * ^
  ^ * * ^
 ^ * * * ^
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

As for converting this to a C++ class, that's an exercise for you to solve.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, but I do need a bit of a clarification. What exactly is the purpose of the variable 'r'?  In the code above you didn't comment as to what is it used for and I am having a hard time trying to figure it out.

Comment: `r` is for mirroring the bottom half of the rows to be identical to the top half of the rows. When `width==6`, we want row 6 to be the same as row 4. Row 7 to be the same as row , row 8 to be the same as row 2, etc... So `r` is the variable that helps make that adjustment.  Notice that `r == row` for the  top portion. But after the middle row is drawn, `r` starts to equal the "mirrored row".

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you!